# Unable to display HH:mm:ss data in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I've got problem to display data in `HH:mm:ss` format in Chart.js. It simply doesn't appear. I want to display this data as duration, it can vary from seconds to hours. I've prepared fiddle with example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vhr69qny/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm, so I find out that it's impossible to set 'time' y-axis
I've solved the problem via code snippet found in issue [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2791).